# regex expression for number only between 1-24 and also allow decimal

Tags: javascript, html, regex, expression

i want regex expression which allow only numbers between 1-24 and also 2 decimal numbers.
should allow following numbers
1
2
3
.
.
24
and 
1.00
1.01
1.02
.
.
24.99

Comment: ^((?:[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:\.\d{1,2})?|24(?:\.00?)?)$     Try this

Comment: @Reshma it is also allowing only 0, it should ignore 0 , other cases are fine

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cR9oB9/5 .Its not allowing 0.check this demo

Comment: ^((?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:\.\d{1,2})?|24(?:\.00?)?)$

Comment: working fine thanks @Reshma

Comment: dont forget to mark as correct answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^((?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:\.\d{1,2})?|24(?:\.00?)?)$
```

Try this

https://regex101.com/r/cR9oB9/5

Comment: This doesn't match `24.99`.

Comment: yes it wont.because he asked for numbers between 1-24 . For 24.99 use below regex

Comment: ^((?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])(?:\.\d{1,2})?|25(?:\.00?)?)$

Comment: @Reshma here is one question , now i want to allow numbers upto 700, so what will be epression?

Comment: @Toto it is allowing 24.99 here, there is no issue about this number